# How to merge two data.frames by the first part of a names in a column?

Tags: r

I have two text files:
f1

```
    A   B
   sam 23
   dam  90
```

f2

```
      G  A  K
  43 DQF_df_gf 65
  54 sam_df_bnol 90
  56 jay_df_nkol 89
  67 dam_df_etr 43
  45 fds_df_lpko 78
```

As you can see here I have two names in f1$A which I want to use to meg with f2 by A . the problem is that they share only the the first parts with f2$A. 
Using :

```
            gh=merge(f1,f2,by="A",all=TRUE)
```

will give no error but rows of NA

desired output:

```
        A   B    G    K
     sam 23   54   90
     dam  90  67   43
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I think you need to make a new column by splitting `A` at first `_`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik This is essentially what I did in my answer, q.v. below.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, there's an example and expected output in the question - not sure what else you are asking for?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I'm lazy, I like having a chunk of code I can copy/paste into an R session and work from there.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, oh I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the first parts of column "A" in `f2` so that you can use it to merge by. If you want to do that in one step including the merge, you could use:

```
merge(f1, transform(f2, A = sub("^([^_]+).*", "\\1", A)), by = "A")
#    A  B  G  K
#1 dam 90 67 43
#2 sam 23 54 90
```

This doesn't require adding a new column to `f2`. It only changes a copy of `f2` that is lost after the `merge`, i.e. `f2` remains unchanged.

You can see that I did this extraction inside the merge:

```
transform(f2, A = sub("^([^_]+).*", "\\1", A))
#   G   A  K
#1 43 DQF 65
#2 54 sam 90
#3 56 jay 89
#4 67 dam 43
#5 45 fds 78
```

Another check:

```
x <- c("KR.S._",  "SS#2_")
sub("^([^_]+).*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "KR.S." "SS#2"
```

Sample data used:

```
f1 <- structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("dam", "sam"
), class = "factor"), B = c(23L, 90L)), .Names = c("A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

f2 <- structure(list(G = c(43L, 54L, 56L, 67L, 45L), A = structure(c(2L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("dam_df_etr", "DQF_df_gf", "fds_df_lpko", 
"jay_df_nkol", "sam_df_bnol"), class = "factor"), K = c(65L, 
90L, 89L, 43L, 78L)), .Names = c("G", "A", "K"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: @temor, so you always need the string before the first `_`? Or what is the exact pattern you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge()` to achieve what you want, but instead of using `df2`, you can merge the `df1` data frame with a data frame consisting of `f2` along with a temporary column for merging:

```
gh <- merge(f1,
            cbind(f2, merge=gsub('^(.*?)_.*', '\\1', f2$A)),
            by.x=c("A"),
            by.y=c("merge"))

> gh
    A  B  G           A  K
1 dam 90 67  dam_df_etr 43
2 sam 23 54 sam_df_bnol 90
```